# Adding attributes to a training set

Tags: machine-learning

If I had a feature calories and another feature number of people, why does adding the feature calorie per person or adding the feature calories/10 help in improving testing? I don't see how performing simple arithmetic on two features will gain you more information.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused by the question. What algorithm are you using? / What are you doing?

Comment: It's just a general question. Like for Kaggle competitions, the top scoring teams preprocess their data and do similar things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you're using a classifier/regression mechanism which is linear (or log-linear) in the feature space. If your instance x has features x_i, then being linear means the score is something like:

y_i = \sum_i x_i * w_i

Now consider you think there are some important interactions between the features---maybe you think that x_i is only important if x_j takes a similar value, or their sum is more important than the individual values, or whatever. One way of incorporating this information is to have the algorithm explicitly model cross products, e.g.:

y_i = [ \sum_i x_i * w_i ]  + [\sum_i,j x_i * x_j * w_ij]

However, linear algorithms are ubiquitous and easy to use, so a way of getting interaction-like terms into your standard linear classifier/regression mechanism is to augment the feature space so for every pair x_i, x_j you create a feature of the form [x_i * x_j] or [x_i / x_j] or whatever. Now you can model interactions between features without needing to use a non-linear algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Performing that type of arithmetic allows you to use that information in models that don't explicitly consider nonlinear combinations of variables.  Some classifiers attempt to find features that best explain/predict the training data and often the best feature may be nonlinear.

Using your data, suppose you wanted to predict whether a group of people will - on average - gain weight.  And suppose the "correct" answer is that the group will gain weight if people in the group consume over an average of 3,000 calories per day.  If your inputs are `group_size` and `group_calories`, you will need to use both of those variables to make an accurate prediction. But if you also provide `group_avg_calories` (which is just `group_calories` / `group_size`), you could just use that single feature to make the prediction. Even if the first two features added some additional information, if you were to feed those 3 features to a decision tree classifier, it would almost certainly pick `group_avg_calories` as the root node and you would end up with a much simpler tree structure. There is also a downside to adding lots of arbitrary nonlinear combinations of features to your model, which is that it can add significantly to the classifier's training time.

With regard to `calories/10`, it's not clear why you would do that specifically, but normalizing the input features can improve convergence rates for some classifiers (e.g., ANNs) and can also provide better performance for clustering algorithms because the input features will all be at the same scale (i.e., distances along different feature axes are comparable).